# FuelPHPのRestコントローラでbeforeメソッドでレスポンスを返却したい。

Tags: php, fuelphp, rest

RestAPIを使用したアプリケーションをFuelPHPで開発しようとしています。

Restコントローラを継承するcontroller\base.phpを作成し、
初期処理はここに書こうとしています。

ここでやりたいことは
beforeメソッド内で、tokenが一致しているかを確認したいです。

```
<?php
namespace Controller;

class Base extends \Controller_Rest {
    protected $format = 'json';

    /* HTTPステータスコード */
    protected $Unauthorized = 401;

    /**
     * 初期処理
     */
    public function before()
    {
        parent::before();

        /* Tokenを確認する */
        $token = '';
        if (\Input::method() === 'GET' || \Input::method() === 'POST') {
            $token = \Input::param('token');
        }
        if (! self::is_token_matched($token)) {
            // 不正なアクセス
            return $this->response(
                [
                    'message' => 'トークンが不正です',
                ],
                $this->Unauthorized
            );
        }
    }
}
```

このソースコードでToken不一致の場合を試すと、
エラーメッセージと401のステータスコードが返されることを期待しているのですが、
実際は、それが子クラスのAPIが呼ばれてしまいます。
下記のような実装も試しましたが、期待していた動作になりませんでした。

```
    if (! self::is_token_matched($token)) {
        // 不正なアクセス
        $this->response(
            [
                'message' => 'トークンが不正です',
            ],
            $this->Unauthorized
        );
        exit;
    }

    if (! self::is_token_matched($token)) {
        // 不正なアクセス
        $this->response(
            [
                'message' => 'トークンが不正です',
            ],
            $this->Unauthorized
        );
        return;
    }
```

beforeメソッドでレスポンスを返却するやりかたをご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、
ご教授いただけると幸いです。

Comment: 「httpステータスコード」「api設計」は新しく作成されたタグのようですが、この質問においてそれは重要なキーワードでしょうか？ステータスコードについて論じているわけではないですし、api設計というより実装についての質問のように見えます。他の質問でも多数のタグを設定・作成されているようですが、たくさんタグをつけると何についての質問なのかが却って伝わりにくくなってしまわないでしょうか。ヘルプセンターもご覧ください： http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。おっしゃる通り実装の質問でしたので該当するタグを削除します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しましたので、解決策を記述します。
RESTコントローラーではrouterメソッドがURLに応じてレスポンスの内容を振り分けているため
共通のエラー処理をbeforeメソッドに書くことは難しいということが分かりました。
したがって、RESTコントローラーで共通のエラー処理を書く場合は、
routerメソッドを使用することになります。

```
<?php
namespace Controller;

class Base extends \Controller_Rest {
    protected $format = 'json';

    /* HTTPステータスコード */
    protected $Unauthorized = 401;

    /**
     * ルーティング処理
     * 
     * @param string $method
     * @param string $params
     */
    public function router($method, $params)
    {
        /* Tokenを確認する */
        $token = '';
        if (\Input::method() === 'GET' || \Input::method() === 'POST') {
            $token = \Input::param('token');
        }
        if (! self::is_token_matched($token)) {
            /* 不正なアクセス */
            $this->response(
                [
                    'message' => 'トークンが不正です',
                ],
                $this->Unauthorized
            );
            return;
        }
        parent::router($method, $params);
    }
}
```